# HTTP Request with Oauth2 to Google App Script Web App

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, httprequest

1. List item

I have created a Google App Script REST - Application (starting with "script.google.com/"), that works with HTTP-requests.

The application works fine when it is available to 'everyone, even anonymous' but when I set it available to my domain only [EDIT:] OR "only myself" from the publish/deploy as WebApp[/EDIT], I can only access the web app with browser and signing in but not with http request.

I have tried requesting an authorization token with both Google [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and an android application based on a [Xamarin Auth Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/).

Both methods have resulted me a working authorization token that I can copy+paste to an other platform an confirm it is working with a request to https://wwww.googlapis.com/plus/v1/people/me.

I can access the Web app with browser and signing in. Now when I call my script with http request I get the following result:

```
"<HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Unauthorized</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY> </HTML>"
```

I have tried to call the Web App with another App Script:

```
var headers =  {
    "authorization": "Bearer [access_token]",
  };   
  var params = {
     method:"GET",
     contentType:"application/json",
     muteHttpExceptions:true,
     headers:headers,    
  };
  var url = "https://script.google.com/[rest_of_the_script_url]";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
```

Also I have tried calling the Web App with C# OAuth2Request (Taken from the Xamarin tutorial):

```
var url = "https://script.google.com/[rest_of_the_script_url]";
var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri(url), null, account );
```

Also I have tried C# HttpWebRequest:

```
string accessToken = "Bearer [access_token]";
string url = "[https://script.google.com/[rest_of_the_script_url]";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.create(url);

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", accessToken);

var response = request.getResponse();
```

All previous methods have the same result: "(401) Unauthorized".

For scopes I have set:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

My WebApp does not require any scopes according to it's properties.
[EDIT:] Also to make sure it does not I did set a doGet() method as simple as possible:

```
function doGet(e)
{
   return ContentService.CreateTextOutput("success");
}
```

This question has been asked before, but some have found the solution and some have not. Also I did not success with the answers either.

1. [I think my first attempt covers this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229361/calling-a-google-apps-script-web-app-with-access-token).
2. [I tried to translate the Java answer to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248772/run-a-google-apps-script-from-android-app)

Ok, thanks for reading down here, wish some one can help me out with this as I'm running out of ideas (and time, eventually).

EDIT:
Though the issue has resolved and turned out to be a scope-issue I am answering the questions in the comments below, in case this question might be of any help to anyone in the future.

Comment: What do you have selected in the corresponding "Execute the app as:" drop down?  Also (despite the lack of required scopes in the properties...), any chance you're calling something that's returning 401 in doGet()? Might be worth trimming down to the two-line doGet() implementation here, just to see if it still repros: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: FWIW, I was able to trivially reproduce this with the two-line example I referenced above. Now I am intrigued.

Comment: Where did you set this? "when I set it available to my domain only"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with an access token authorized with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope in the Google OAuth Playground.

That doesn't seem quite right in my opinion, but it's the least permissive scope I got to work.